# LINQ Select Records X Minutes apart

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a simple table that keeps track of the entry date. I would like to select records that are X minutes apart.

```
IMAGE_LOCATION  IMAGE DATE
============== =============
2227.jpg    08/03/2014 22:27:47
2228.jpg    08/03/2014 22:28:48
2229.jpg    08/03/2014 22:59:49
2230.jpg    08/03/2014 23:12:50
2231.jpg    08/03/2014 23:29:49
```

From the sample above i would like the query to return items that are at least X minutes apart, lets say 30 min. so from the list above 2227.jpg, 2229.jpg and 2231.jpg would be returned only.

This is what i have so far that just returns the latest images, however i need the latest ones but separated by at least 30 minutes between records.

```
using (var db = new GibFrontierEntities())
{
    var result = (from u in db.CCTV_IMAGES.OrderByDescending(u => u.ImageDate)
                  select u).Take(rows);
    return result.ToList();
}
```

Comment: This is so easy with a simple `foreach` that you shouldn't even try to write a LINQ one-liner for it.

Comment: @GertArnold I assume he would like to do this pre-enumeration so that he can perform the operation on the SQL server. But you're right, since they're always taking the last 30 anyway, it's probably easier in C# than it is in SQL

Comment: Last two records are also 30 min apart. Why they are not selected instead?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy The second to last item is less than 30 minutes from the item that preceded it.  The last item is more than 30 minutes after the last included item, so it *is* included.

Comment: Create a stored procedure on the DB end that uses a cursor to traverse the query and include the appropriate items.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick attempt to achieve exactly what you asked for, a LINQ solution (tested and working in .NET 4):

```
var list = db.CCTV_IMAGES.OrderByDescending(u => u.ImageDate);
return list.Where((d, i) =>
        {
            //Look ahead to compare against the next if it exists.
            if (list.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 1) != null)
            {
                return d.ImageDate.Subtract(list.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 1).ImageDate).TotalMinutes > 30;
            }

            //Look behind to compare against the previous if this is the last item in the list.
            if (list.ElementAtOrDefault(i - 1) != null)
            {
                return list.ElementAtOrDefault(i - 1).ImageDate.Subtract(d.ImageDate).TotalMinutes > 30;
            }

            return false;
        }).ToList();
```

**Per comments and a clearer definition of the requirement:**

Because you stated in the comments below that you will have 1 item a minute and you previously stated that you need them separated by *at least* 30 minutes, would you consider simplifying the logic to grab every 30th item from the list?

```
return list.Where((d, i) => i % 30 == 0);
```

Comment: This seems to throw an exception.

Comment: What is the exception?  I apologize, I don't have the ability to test the code at the moment.

Comment: This isn't a valid LINQ query. The lambda expression passed to the `Where` method only takes one argument.

Comment: Ah yes, you are absolutely correct. I completely forget about the overloaded `Where` method that includes the index of the source element.

Comment: @Tommy My update will also now include the last item of the list, provided it's predecessor was 30 minutes earlier.  Simply remove the condition if you would not like it included.

Comment: Hi, this returns an empty list even though there is sufficient data??

Comment: My data contains one image every 1 minute, therefore if you are comparing one against the other no matches will ever be greater than 30 min. I need to simply pick one entry every 30 min interval or so.

Comment: Oh, I don't think your original question adequately described that requirement.  You might consider revising the question.  A simpler approach might be then to select every 30th list item rather than complicating the logic with time comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to achieve what you want:

```
using (var db = new GibFrontierEntities())
{
    var images = db.CCTV_IMAGES;
    var result = images
        .SelectMany(i => images,
            (first, second) => new { First = first, Second = second })
        .Where(i => i.First != i.Second)
        .Where(i => Math.Abs(
            EntityFunctions
                .DiffMinutes(i.First.ImageDate, i.Second.ImageDate)) >= 30)
        .Select(i => i.First)
        .Distinct()
        .OrderByDescending(i => i.ImageDate)
        .Take(rows)
        .ToList();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What overload of SelectMany is that?

Comment: This will return every item for which there is at least one other time that is more than X minutes from it.  That's just not right.  For example, the second item in the example has items more than 30 minutes from it, but the item directly preceding it is within the threshold, so it is excluded.  You need to pair each item up with *the item that preceded it, not every single other item in the list.

Comment: I provided a link to the specific overload in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned already, this could be easily achievable through iteration. However, it you really have to deal with LINQ expression, here's a quick and dirty sample that will return dates that are 30 minutes apart:

```
List<DateTime> dateLlist = new List<DateTime>();

        dateLlist.Add(new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));
        dateLlist.Add(new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0));
        dateLlist.Add(new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 1, 45, 0, 0));

        DateTime previousTime = new DateTime();
        bool shouldAdd = false;
        List<DateTime> newList = dateLlist.Where(x =>
        {
            shouldAdd = (previousTime == DateTime.MinValue || previousTime.AddMinutes(30) < x);
            previousTime = x;
            return shouldAdd;
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Entity Framework won't understand how to translate this into a SQL query.