# Returning LINQ list X minutes apart

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, grouping

There is a similar question that was resolved previously and I have tried to use their code but turn it into a generic function e.g. [LINQ Select Records X Minutes apart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326418/linq-select-records-x-minutes-apart)

I am trying to build a function that will return a list of objects that are always 2 hours apart. You must also pass the DateTime property name into this function i.e. "Time" if the list DateTime field is called "Time".

It kind of works already, however, it's not working perfectly. I suspect the calculation within the grouping needs a tweak. I have tried:

```
((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).Hour % 2

((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).Hour - 2

((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).Hour * 2
```

They either don't return the expected result or throw an exception:

```
"Hour, Minute, and Second parameters describe an un-representable DateTime."
```

This is currently what it looks like:

```
public static class ICollectionExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetByHoursApart<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string dateTimePropertyName)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("source");
        }

        Type myType = typeof(T);
        IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(myType.GetProperties());
        var property = props.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == dateTimePropertyName);

        if (property.PropertyType != typeof(DateTime))
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException(dateTimePropertyName);
        }

        return source.GroupBy(x =>
        {
            return 
                new DateTime(((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).Year, 
                            ((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).Month, 
                            ((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).Day, 
                            ((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).Hour / 2, 
                            0, 
                            0);

        }).Select(x => (T)x.First()).Distinct().ToList();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I have now also tried the following with a similar result set.

```
public static class ICollectionExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetByHoursApart<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int hoursApart, string dateTimePropertyName)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("source");
        }

        Type myType = typeof(T);
        IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(myType.GetProperties());
        var property = props.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == dateTimePropertyName);

        if (property.PropertyType != typeof(DateTime))
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException(dateTimePropertyName);
        }

        return source.GroupBy(x =>
        {
            return
                new DateTime(((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).Year,
                            ((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).Month,
                            ((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).Day,
                            ((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).AddHours(-((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).Hour % hoursApart).Hour,
                            ((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).AddMinutes(-((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).Minute).Minute,
                            ((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).AddSeconds(-((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).Second).Second);

        }).Select(x => (T)x.First()).Distinct().ToList();
    }
}
```

**RESOLVED:**

I have found the solution in filtering the groups. Ensuring the Time is the same hour as the group instead of allowing any value that resides inside the 2 hour groups to be true. Here is the finished code:

```
public static class ICollectionExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetByHoursApart<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int hoursApart, string dateTimePropertyName)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("source");
        }

        Type myType = typeof(T);
        IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(myType.GetProperties());
        var property = props.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == dateTimePropertyName);

        if (property.PropertyType != typeof(DateTime))
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException(dateTimePropertyName);
        }

        return source.GroupBy(x =>
        {
            return
            new DateTime(((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).Year,
                        ((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).Month,
                        ((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).Day,
                        ((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).AddHours(-((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).Hour % hoursApart).Hour,
                        ((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).AddMinutes(-((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).Minute).Minute,
                        ((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).AddSeconds(-((DateTime)property.GetValue(x)).Second).Second);

        }).Where(x => x.Key.Hour == ((DateTime)property.GetValue(x.First())).Hour).Select(x => (T)x.First()).Distinct().ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe your expectation is wrong. If your source is Empty or has one element only, you will end up with zero or one group only. Better you provide some sample input.
Right now with division, you group by hours that give the same result then being devided by 2. So (4,5) is one group, (6,7) is one group etc. Looks good so far.
The distinct at the end seems to be useless, things cannot be equal if they differ in Datetimeproperty.